# Bootstrap validation. How can i treat zero as null?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

The rendered html of my form is

```
    <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
        <label class="form-label" for="SalePrice">Sale price</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="SalePrice" type="number" name="SalePrice" min="0" max="99999" step="0.10" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
            The field is required
        </div>
    </div>
```

When no value is entered, validation works great. `The field is required` is displayed.

But how can i treat also zero as null?

If the user enters 0 as input, no validation occurs.

Can i extend the required property for zero values also?

Comment: You could change the "min" value to "0.10"

Comment: Bootstrap Validation is not the same as the jQuery Validate plugin.  Please tag correctly.  Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really confused of HTML5 validation(you mentioned here it as bootstrap validation) and jQuery Validation. Both are different in perspective of development aspects.

So for differentiate both aspects i added 2 forms, first one with normal HTML5 validation and second with jQyery validate plugin. Both full fills your expectation but jQuery will be bit better so that HTML5 depends on your browser.

```js
$(function() {

  $("form#val2").validate({
    rules: {
      SalePrice: {
        required: true,
        number: true,
        minlength: 0,
        range: [0.1, 99999]
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      SalePrice: {
        required: "Sale Price is Required",
        number: "Enter a valid number",
        minlength: jQuery.validator.format("At least {0} characters required!"),
      },
      email: {
        required: "Email is required",
        email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  form {
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
  }
  
  label.error {
    color: red;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
  
  .submit {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .form-label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<div class="container">

  <form id="val" action="" method="post">
    <h4>Validation With HTML5</h4>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="SalePrice">Sale price</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="SalePrice" type="number" name="SalePrice" min="0.1" max="99999" step="0.10" required="">
      <button id="submit" class="submit btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <form id="val2" action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <h4>Validation with <a href="https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/">jQuery Validation Plugin</a></h4>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="SalePrice">Sale price</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="SalePrice" type="number" name="SalePrice" min="0.1" max="99999" step="0.10">
      <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="email" type="email" name="email">
      <button id="submit1" class="submit btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

> In second form HTML5 validation is restricted using "novalidate" in
>   form tag

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, we can do it in two ways.
    1)No need to write any validations in jquery, Directly We need to use form validation. When submitting the form or any page button class provide as submit and use form submit.
    FOR EX:-

```
<div class="container">
  <form id="val" action="" method="post">
    <h4>Validation With HTML5</h4>
    <div class="form-group col-xl-6">
      <label class="form-label" for="SalePrice">Sale price</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="SalePrice" type="number" name="SalePrice" min="0.1" max="99999" step="0.10" required="">
      <button id="btnSubmit" class="submit btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>`
```

2)In the bootstrap part, you assigned an invalid-feedback class div element. If you want to display div element as the feedback message for input validation then you can follow this code in jquery.

```
`<div class="form-group col-xl-6">
        <label class="form-label" for="SalePrice">Sale price</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="SalePrice" type="number" name="SalePrice" min="0" max="99999" step="0.10" required="">
        <div class="invalid-feedback" style="display:none">
            The field is required
        </div>
    </div>`


    `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#SalePrice").change(function(){
    var saleprice = parseInt(($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == 0) ? 0 : $(this).val());
    if(saleprice == 0)
        $(".invalid-feedback").show();
        else
        $(".invalid-feedback").hide();    
});
});
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can validate further to achieve it like this:

```
$('#SalePrice').on('keyup', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 0){
        alert("Price Not Accepted!");
        $(this).val("");
    }
})
```